Prevalence upper bound when no events are observed in sample
In a sample of 2000 observations, no positive cases were found, but I want to still be able to provide an upper bound for the prevalence.
The general rule that people seem to use is to simply take 3/n, but this is the just same as the upper bound at 95% for 1 case found in the sample.
3/2000=0.15% and the upper bound at 95% for a prevalence of 1 in 2000 is 0.15%.
Surely if 0 cases are observed the upper bound should be lower than if 1 case was found? Are there any other methods I could use to keep in line with the upper bounds at a certain confidence level for other frequency results?

How do you arrive at your statement that the upper limit for 1 out of 2000 is 0.15%? Are you using a two-sided interval there but a one-sided interval for 0 out of 2000?

@mdewey two-sided for the upper limit of 1. I guess the upper bound for the 0 case is one sided, but this was just an approximation that I saw recommended in various places using the simple calculation mentioned. Ultimately, I'm not sure how I should create an upper bound for prevalence for 0 cases in 2000 that would be comparable to other results sets I have that have two-sided intervals for other higher prevalence

It does not make sense, at least to me, to calculate a two-sided CI when you know that values below zero are impossible.

How are you doing your calculations?  If they're correct, they should be extremely close to the Poisson confidence limits illustrated at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/488834/919.  I obtain prevalences (as 95% UCLs) of $2.996/2000$ and $4.744/2000$ for observing zero and one positive cases, respectively.

@mdewey the lower bound would only be below zero for some of the results though and for these I would still like to have a two-sided CI.  Are you suggesting I should use a one sided interval when the lower bound is below zero? But then it seems strange if I have any comparison between the two results - e.g. if I use one-sided for the 0 case, but my other test has 4 cases identified, then it feels like I should have a two-sided CI for it, but then the upper bound can't really be compared between the two tests

@mdewey Maybe what I should really be asking is - what formula can I use to calculate CIs for prevalence when there are 0 observations? As currently I am only using the very simplistic 3/n, which sounded like it's more a rule of thumb..

You do not need any "rule of thumb" such as $\frac 3 n$, when you can compute it directly, using binomial confidence intervals.
You also should not use double sided CI's, as you want a "worse case" prevalence, so are only interested in the upper bound.
If you compute a single sided CI of the proportion, using 0 "failures" out of 2000, you get an upper prevalence of $2.9935$ per $2000$, or $0.15$%. (very close to @whuber's value, because for low proportions, Poisson is a very good approximation to the binomial). This is your upper prevalence bound, at 95% confidence (i.e. there is only a 5% chance that the prevalence would be greater). It "jumps" to $.23% for 99% confidence.
You can use this online calculator to play with the numbers.


The general rule that people seem to use is to simply take $3/n$

(which in your case is 0.15%). This is sometimes called the "rule of three", and there are many questions here about this. (I do not close as duplicate, since this Q & answers also invoke the Poisson distribution).

Revisiting the Rule of Three
Is Rule of Three inappropriate in some cases?
When to use (and not use) the rule of three

and search the site.
